# JPA EntityManagerFactory with persistence.xml and Properties Map

Tags: java, jpa, connection-string, java-7, persistence.xml

Can I pass *some* properties to an `EntityManagerFactory` by code, while still maintaining `persistence.xml` as the main configuration source? Using `createEntityManager`'s overload with a `Map` appears to override `persistence.xml` completely:

```
Map<String, String> propertyMap;
factory.createEntityManager(propertyMap);
```

I'd like to configure JPA in `persistence.xml`, but pass in a custom connection string. I'm using HSQL and I'd like to compose a custom DB-file path with the current user directory, which I have to get by code (as far as I know).

It would be great if I could keep `persistence.xml` anyway, as I'd not have to write a custom configuration mechanism.

Comment: I would load the properties from persistence.xml, replace/add the desired values and create the entitymanager from the properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean

```
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(puName, props);
```

unless of course you mean you have created the EMF first and want to apply props after that?

Comment: Great hint, did not think of creating the factory differently. Seems to work. Thank you!